# Linux kernel cfs_tasks

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler

What does cfs_tasks in struct rq represent? Is it a list of (all) tasks waiting to be scheduled on that CPU?

As far as I know, CFS is short for Completely Fair Scheduler, but I am thinking if it encompasses all tasks in runqueue, regardless of their scheduling algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

CFS only manages normal priority tasks. There are also rt_rq and dl_rq managing real time and deadline tasks, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The 'cfs_tasks' list is a MRU(Most Recently Used) list. CFS scheduler add task  to this list when task is enqueue to runqueue(woken up), and remove task from this list when the task is sleep. This MRU list is used for load balance.